# How can I stop my device open being reset to iPhoto

Tags: snow-leopard, photos.app, graphics

When I plug in my Camera (Toshiba Camileo H20), it always opens in iPhoto. Because I want a little more control over the import process, I would like Image Capture to be the default app for it.

When I open up Image Capture to change the 'connecting this camera opens' drop down, and select another app, as soon as my mouse has left the selection, it reverts back to iPhoto. This is regardless of which other option I select.

The computer is an iMac 2009, with OS X 10.6.5 (Snow Leopard), and Image Capture v6.0.1 (428). The Camera is connected via USB, and appears in Image Capture as 2 Mass storage devices (internal + the card). The card device (2nd) is exhibiting this problem, the first device does have Image Capture set as its default when connected.

Other notes - each device now has a different name (Not just NO NAME for both).

How can I stop Image Capture reverting my choice for behaviour when the camera is connected?

Comment: Okay - both the memory card in the device, and the internal storage on it were showing up as mass storage devices with 'NO NAME'. Finder only has one icon, yet Image capture had two. Renaming the one showing in finder named only the internal storage. Then removing the camera, and reinserting it showed TWO devices in Finder. This however still didn't change the dropdown behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image Capture and iPhoto have cache locations to store the status of pictures and camera roll information for each device. It's likely those preferences and databases are corrupt.

If you have a recent backup, you might try quitting the apps and cleaning some of these by moving them to the trash:

~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Image_Capture*
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iPhoto/Cache.db

Without emptying the trash you can reboot and test to see that it fixes the issue and doesn't cause other issues before emptying the trash. You can quit the apps and move things back if it causes you issues - but these should be regenerated from a normally working system (and yours is either slightly confused or potentially not working so well)

Comment: Yep. There is another place your settings for that device are placed iirc, but if I couldnt change a setting I would be looking for a plist to delete or a cache to regenerate. +1

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is quite odd behaviour. I would try clicking 'Other' in that drop down menu, and then clicking 'Image Capture' from the Applications folder windows that drops down. This may make it work. Hope this helps.